# Connecting STM32F407VET06 to W5500 Ethernet

Tags: stm32, ethernet, stm32f407

I'm newbie about these issues. I'm trying to connect stm32f407vet to w5500.

Those pins were connected like following :

```
INT -> IRQ
CS  -> CS
SCK -> SP_1 SCK (PB_3)
MOSI -> PB_5
MISO -> PB_4
RST -> RST
NC ->  NC
V -> 3.3
GND -> GND
```

But Assigning IP address to ethernet module failed.

Ethernet module is connected Modem via ethernet cables and on the other hand with stm32.
And Wiznet IO library used in software side.

Here is code :

```
  wizchip_init(bufSize, bufSize);
  wiz_NetInfo netInfo = { .mac     = {0x00, 0x08, 0xdc, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef},    // Mac address
                          .ip     = {192, 168, 1, 192},                    // IP address
                          .sn     = {255, 255, 255, 0},                    // Subnet mask
                          .gw     = {192, 168, 1, 1}};                    // Gateway address
  wizchip_setnetinfo(&netInfo);
  wizchip_getnetinfo(&netInfo);
```

Hence the IP adresses in netinfo turns into "FF,FF,FF,FF", when the program is run.

I'm confused about what I do next. I need your guides and helps.

Thank you, bests.

[image: STM32_F4]

[image: W5500 Lite]

Comment: There could be a number of problems both hardware and software. You need to debug your system and find out what is working and what isn’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is verify that each pin is functioning. Get into the code and test each pin and make sure the logic levels  are correct and that you are actually talking to the pin that you intended to.

Get a logic analyzer (usb logic analyzers are cheap) and hook it up to the w5500 make sure the messages that you send have the correct clock and logic levels (verify this in the datasheet)

If that is correct then try and read back a register over SPI (set the IP register and read it back). Then you should be good to go.